# How to implement network using Bert as a paragraph encoder in long text classification, in keras?

Tags: python, keras, nlp, bert-language-model

I am doing a long text classification task, which has more than 10000 words in doc, I am planing to use Bert as a paragraph encoder, then feed the embeddings of paragraph to BiLSTM step by step.
The network is as below:

> Input: (batch_size, max_paragraph_len, max_tokens_per_para,embedding_size)
>
> bert layer: (max_paragraph_len,paragraph_embedding_size)
>
> lstm layer: ???
>
> output layer: (batch_size,classification_size)

How to implement it with keras?
I am using keras's load_trained_model_from_checkpoint to load bert model

```
bert_model = load_trained_model_from_checkpoint(
        config_path,
        model_path,
        training=False,
        use_adapter=True,
        trainable=['Encoder-{}-MultiHeadSelfAttention-Adapter'.format(i + 1) for i in range(layer_num)] +
            ['Encoder-{}-FeedForward-Adapter'.format(i + 1) for i in range(layer_num)] +
            ['Encoder-{}-MultiHeadSelfAttention-Norm'.format(i + 1) for i in range(layer_num)] +
            ['Encoder-{}-FeedForward-Norm'.format(i + 1) for i in range(layer_num)],
        )
```

Comment: You may be interested in Bert-as-service, which is a package specifically for using Bert to get document embedding. If for sone reason you want to implement it yourself, read how the package works (pooling the second to last layer)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can check the following [article](https://medium.com/@brn.pistone/bert-fine-tuning-for-tensorflow-2-0-with-keras-api-9913fc1348f6).  The author shows how to load a pre-trained BERT model, embed it into a Keras layer and use it into a customized Deep Neural Network.
First install TensorFlow 2.0 Keras implementation of google-research/bert:

`pip install bert-for-tf2`

Then run:

```
import bert
import os

def createBertLayer():
    global bert_layer

    bertDir = os.path.join(modelBertDir, "multi_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12")

    bert_params = bert.params_from_pretrained_ckpt(bertDir)

    bert_layer = bert.BertModelLayer.from_params(bert_params, name="bert")

    bert_layer.apply_adapter_freeze()

def loadBertCheckpoint():

    modelsFolder = os.path.join(modelBertDir, "multi_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12")
    checkpointName = os.path.join(modelsFolder, "bert_model.ckpt")

    bert.load_stock_weights(bert_layer, checkpointName)
```