# Is splitting a long document of a dataset for BERT considered bad practice?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, classification, bert-language-model, text-classification

I am fine-tuning a BERT model on a labeled dataset with many documents longer than the 512 token limit set by the tokenizer.
Since truncating would lose a lot of data I would rather use, I started looking for a workaround. However I noticed that simply splitting the documents after 512 tokens (or another heuristic) and creating new entries in the dataset with the same label was never mentioned.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58643108/11614170) answer, someone mentioned that you would need to recombine the predictions, is that necessary when splitting the documents?

Is this generally considered bad practice or does it mess with the integrity of the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not mentioned if your intention is to classify, but given that you refer to an article on classification I will refer to an approach where you classify the whole text.

The main question is - which part of the text is the most informative for your purpose - or - in other words - does it make sense to use more than the first / last split of text?

When considering long passages of text, frequently, it is enough to consider the first (or last) 512 tokens to *correctly* predict the class in substantial majority of cases (say 90%). Even though you may loose some precision, you gain on speed and performance of the overall solution *and* you are getting rid of a nasty problem of figuring out the correct class out of a set of classifications. Why?

Consider an example of text 2100 tokens long. You split it by 512 tokens, obtaining pieces: 512, 512, 512, 512, 52 (notice the small last piece - should you even consider it?). Your target class for this text is, say, A, however you get the following predictions on the pieces: A, B, A, B, C. So you have now a headache to figure out the right method to determine the class. You can:

- use majority voting but it is not conclusive here.
- weight the predictions by the length of the piece. Again non conclusive.
- check that prediction of the last piece is class C but it is barely above the threshold and class C is kinda A. So you are leaning towards A.
- re-classify starting the split from the end. In the same order as before you get: A, B, C, A, A. So, clearly A. You also get it when you majority vote combining all of the classifications (forward and backward splits).
- consider the confidence of the classifications, e.g. A: 80, B: 70, A: 90, B: 60, C: 55% - avg. 85% for A vs. 65% for B.
- reconfirm the correction of labelling of the last piece manually: if it turns out to be B, then it changes all of the above.
- then you can train an additional network to classify out of the *raw* classifications of pieces. Getting again into trouble of figuring out what to do with particularly long sequences or non-conclusive combinations of predictions resulting in poor confidence of the additional classification layer.

It turns out that there is no easy way. And you will notice that text is a strange classification material exhibiting all of the above (and more) issues while typically the difference in agreement between the first piece prediction and the annotation vs. the ultimate, perfect classifier is slim at best.

**So, spare the effort and strive for simplicity, performance, and heuristic... and clip it!**

On details of the best practices you should probably refer to the article from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59778726/6573902).