# Perform sentiment analysis using pertained huggingFace model

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-tokenizers

I am using [this hugging face model](https://huggingface.co/cardiffnlp/twitter-xlm-roberta-base-sentiment) to perform sentiment analysis, this model can handle the text with max tokens 514, What is the best practice to make it work when the tokens greater that 514? i.e long text without truncation, I used truncation, but the problem with truncation it takes only a part from the text not the whole text

I know some inputs have been provided for this questions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58636587/how-to-use-bert-for-long-text-classification) , but it does not fit my application

Comment: As far as I am aware, context length is a fairly set property of a given model; I would think you would either be following the approaches in the previous post you've linked, or you are looking at extending the context window of the model which is non-trivial.